# Ler unsigned char em C

Tags: char

Boa tarde, estou com problemas para ler com scanf uma variável que declarei como unsigned char, ele simplesmente buga meu programa todo ao escrever uma letra. Gostaria de saber como ler um unsigned char em C; já tentei usar "scanf("%hhu", &ch);" e "scanf("%c", &ch);" porém ambos não funcionaram, vi que estão transformando a letra que digito em 0;

Comment: Tu poderias fornecer um exemplo mínimo que reproduza o problema? A princípio, bastaria seguir [o que diz a documentação, nesse link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: Então fiz um programa de fila que em certo case do switch ele pede para digitar um unsigned char para colocar na fila, porém ao digitar uma letra qualquer o scanf meu está ignorando a letra e devolvendo 0 no lugar.                               
                   ` case 3: scanf("%hh", &ch);
    F = pushFila(F,ch);
    break; `      Logo em seguida o programa entra em loop do nada pois para de ler meus outros scanf que estão fora do switch.